# IIS 7.5 Reverse proxy authenticate requests before forwarding

Tags: authentication, iis-7.5, reverse-proxy

I have an internal site that I would like to make available externally. But, I would like to make it available only to a mobile app of my making.

The internal site cannot be altered unfortunately, and cannot be made available externally on it's own. It also has no authentication mechanism of it's own.

my thinking was to have a reverse proxy setup that would only forward requests that come from my application.

Is there a way to authenticate a request coming in at the proxy level and if authentication is passed then allow the forward.

I was thinking maybe a daily code in the url?

does this sound feasible, or is there a standard way to achieve this?. I hope that makes sense!

Martyn

Comment: A similar question here with an answer that I posted: https://serverfault.com/questions/858798/iis-enable-authentication-for-reverse-proxy/961343#961343